# "We don't know the answer" is an appropriate reason to close a question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Recently I have asked the question [on how many Atilla the Hun has killed](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16613/what-was-approximate-attila-the-hun-death-toll). I showed research and question is plain and simple. Atilla the Hun is considered to be in Top most vicious people, however I could not find any data on how much he approximately killed which makes it hard to compare him to others. User Samuel Russell came over said that he didn't know the answer (and there is none) and then closed the question.

Do you think that "We don't know the answer" is it something you consider an appropriate reason to close a question?

Comment: x/0 does not have an answer. This is different, Atilla killed certain amount of people and there must be an answer. It may not be very accurate, but that's different discussion (on accuracy).

Comment: Every question can have an "answer" if you choose to ignore whether the answer is correct. Usually we admit there's no answer rather than insist one be invented.

Answer (score 2):

The question raised as evidence (which is revisiting the closure, not the principle of the closure) is unanswerable by historiographical techniques.  Any answer provided would lack any validity as a historical answer, it would amount to speculation and misrepresentation.

It is my position that until informed otherwise by the community, as appears to be happening at the linked potential duplicate, it is reasonable to close questions that are not historiographically answerable as unanswerable, as this is a site dedicated to historical questions.